# I cannot run my Android app ever since I signed it in order to export for Google Play - Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android

I used Export Wizard to create and sign a certificate for google play.
Ever since that, when I connect my phone to the computer and try to RUN the project, I get a message that there are errors in the project, but there is no red X next to any package nor there is an error in the Errors pane?

```
Your project contains error(s), please fix it before running it
```

The first time I tried, I got a "key has been tampered or password is incorrect" error, but that disappeared as well.

Tried once more, it appeared again:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error generating final archive: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect  MainActivity        Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

EDIT: I was able to run the project by deleting the file at:

```
c:\users\my user\.android\debug.keystore
```

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the application first? If the public key of the signature of your app changes, Android will reject any attempts to install the new version over the old version.

Comment: I had uninstalled the old version before I tried to install the new one

Comment: Since you found the solution, you could post an answer to your own question since it may help other users.